# Top Bar unaware that I have read messages via Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, top-bar, global-inbox

My phone alerts me that I have a new message in my Stack Overflow inbox. After I read the new message in the Android app it shows 0 unread messages. The next time I visit the main site on my notebook the new (December 2013) Top Bar says that I have one unread message: the message that I read on my phone. Even if I shut down my browser and wait a few minutes (to give the Android app time to "sync", or whatever), the new message indicator in the new Top Bar doesn't go away until I click it.

I don't recall this happening with the older top bar, so perhaps the new Top Bar and the Android app need to get better acquainted.

Comment: I have noticed this as well.

Comment: As the mobile apps are no longer supported I'm closing this as no longer reproducable.

Answer (score 2):

These are different mechanisms for the moment, but will be consolidated in the near future as we fully remove the last remnants of the old inbox infrastructure.

Comment: Approaching 2 years, is this still planned? :)

Comment: Was it ever done, over 4 years later??