# Should clicking on inbox items remove them from the new inbox items on the site?

Tags: bug, global-inbox, ios-app

After getting an inbox notification in the app, clicking on the notification de-highlights it in the app but does not acknowledge the notification on the site itself. Should it do so?

Comment: Since it's presumably just using the API's `/inbox` route, the answer would currently be "no." There is an [API feature request](https://stackapps.com/questions/4107/inbox-item-not-marked-as-read-after-viewing) that would address this, although maybe the apps can handle it in a different way.

Comment: Indeed, I suppose my question was rhetorical since my [SENotifier](https://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x) app has the same behaviour. :)

Comment: This is "cross app" issue... already [planned for a fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210433/152859) in the android app so pretty sure it will also fix the same thing in iOS app too. (thus closing as dupe)